# Problems updating current user information PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

i'm currently working on a user profile system...   I'm stuck at the stage where the user updates their information.   I'm checking whether the users newly chosen email address already exists in the database. Currently I'm echoing out their current email address into an input value in a form.

The validation error received is preventing the user from updating their other information if their email remains the same as its already in the db....  any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks

```
$signedin = $_SESSION['username'];

function userExists($db, $email)
{
    $userQuery = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '$email' and email != '$signedin'";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($userQuery);
    $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $email));
    return !!$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}



$email = $_POST['email'];
$exists = userExists($db, $email);
if($exists)
{
    header("Location: memberAccount.php?action=email_In_Use");
}
else
{
    //submit form data
```

Comment: ok so if the user doesn't change his current email address(which you echoed out to him in the input field) and updates other information in the form and hits submit it fails(since email already exists) is that the problem ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Where do I start?

1. You're putting variables right into the query
2. You do not use markers
3. Although 2, you are trying to bind a value to a marker

Looks like you do not understand what PDO is all about.

The right code for you would be this:

```
$userQuery = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = :email and email != :signedin";
$stmt = $db->prepare($userQuery);
$stmt->execute(array(':email' => $email, ':signedin' => $signedin));
```

And it also eludes me why you are using `!!` when you return:

```
return !!$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Should be just

```
return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I also advice on reading [How Prepared Statements Work](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you have logic somewhat correct in your userExists() function, but you've declared the $signedin variable outside the scope of function and it can't access it. Moreover the PDO params are not set properly,

Modify your code like this,

```
$signedin = $_SESSION['username'];

function userExists($db, $email)
{
    global $signedin;
    $userQuery = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = :email and email != :signed_in";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($userQuery);
    $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $email, ':signed_in' => $signedin));
    return $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

read more about variable scopes here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't resolve the issue, i'll keep trying... Thanks for the link, I will read soon.  Thanks again.